# How to execute a command when a player is at a specific coordinate? (1.14+)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do i execute a command whenever a player is at a specific coordinate in 1.14+ Minecraft commands?

Im trying to execute a tellraw when they are at a specific coordinate

I tried doing this in a repeating/always active/unconditional command block

`execute if entity @p positioned x y z`

then i would put a comparator for power to the impulse/need redstone/unconditional command block with the command

`tellraw @p "Example"`

but nothing would happen.

I tried putting the tellraw with the execute command block but it would just repeat the tellraw, or making the command block not on repeat does nothing.

Comment: Duplicate of https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/386436/how-to-execute-a-command-when-a-player-is-at-a-specific-coordinate-1-14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
execute if entity @p[x=87,y=77,z=20,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] run tellraw @p "Example"
```

This will run if the player is in the 87, 77, 20 block.

Comment: Tried to code didn't work. Maybe tell me what like conditions, types of the cmd block, and if it needs redstone or not?

Comment: You can run it in a repeat, unconditional, always active command block, and the command will run on loop as long as the player is in the block. This command is an example of a condition for a command to only run if the player is at a specific position.

Comment: this does work. But the text repeats, and i dont want that.

Comment: You can add command blocks that trigger an additional condition you made, so this will only run once.

Comment: Yes i solved it by using another commmand block thats impulse, with a comparator. THANK YOU